# How to make a exported function wait until the async function above is done loading?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I have a `foo.js` file that is exporting a synchronous function like so:

```js
/* foo.js */
let db;
(async function(){
   db = await somethingAsynchronous();
})();

module.exports = {
    bar: () => {
        return db.get('foobar');
    }
}
```

```js
/* oof.js */
const foo = require('./foo.js');

const gopher = () => {
    console.log(foo.bar());
}
```

Since `bar()` needs to wait until the asynchronous function above needs to finish loading, calling `gopher()` the second `oof.js` loads returns an error - whereas waiting a while and calling `gopher()` is fine. How would I make `bar()` wait until the async function above has finished loading?

I can't move the async function, as there are other exports that use the `db` variable.

Comment: Instead of exporting an instance to a DB,  export a promise to get the DB,. Everywhere you need the DB instance you can then just do `const db = await getDb;`.  Yes, it will require refactoring other units, but in the long run is the better option. Alternatively you could create another promise that gets resolved when your db had been initialized and use this to wait on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `bar` is depending on an asynchronous task to finish, it should itself be asynchronous.

```
 const db = somethingAsynchronous();
 
 async function bar() {
   return (await db).get('foobar');
 }
```

Comment: I had to modify the asynchronous function to a named function instead of an anonymous one, but it worked!